# Are Managed Properties automatically created for site columns in subsites?

Tags: 2013, site-column, sub-site, managed-property

I'm trying to understand how this works. If I create a subsite, and put a site column in it, will SharePoint automatically create the Managed Property?

My experience so far is that Managed Properties are automatically created for site columns added to my root site collection. But they don't seem to be automatically created for site columns added to my subsites.

Answer (score 0):

If the SiteColumn has values in it then it automatically becomes managed properties when crawled. Refer to this article:  [Automatically created managed properties in SharePoint Server 2013](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj613136.aspx?tduid=(4c10b5a31e50b9cc40201b3e9c38d849)(256380)(2459594)(TnL5HPStwNw-PB12gDbGBril8dESOwA3Iw)())

Comment: Is this true for subsites as well?